# How to sort an array by 2 elements in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google script and I have an array like so

```
[
  {RowOfEnemy=0.0, BonusType=, Alive=true, TotalHealth=4350000.0, Matched=false}, 
  {Alive=true, BonusType=, Matched=false, TotalHealth=3900000.0, RowOfEnemy=1.0}, 
  {Matched=true, Alive=true, TotalHealth=3780000.0, RowOfEnemy=2.0, BonusType=MELEE}
]
```

I want to sort on Matched and then TotalHealth both descending. I know how to sort on a single element but I am stumped on sorting 2 elements. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const obj = [{ RowOfEnemy: 0.0, BonusType: "", Alive: true, TotalHealth: 4350000.0, Matched: false }, { Alive: true, BonusType: "", Matched: false, TotalHealth: 3900000.0, RowOfEnemy: 1.0 }, { Matched: true, Alive: true, TotalHealth: 3780000.0, RowOfEnemy: 2.0, BonusType: "MELEE" }];
obj.sort((a, b) => a["TotalHealth"] > b["TotalHealth"] ? 1 : -1);
obj.sort((a, b) => a["Matched"] < b["Matched"] ? 1 : -1);
console.log(obj)
```

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. The values of "Matched" and "TotalHealth" are reordered in descending order.

```js
[
  { Matched: true, Alive: true, TotalHealth: 3780000, RowOfEnemy: 2, BonusType: 'MELEE' },
  { RowOfEnemy: 0, BonusType: '', Alive: true, TotalHealth: 4350000, Matched: false },
  { Alive: true, BonusType: '', Matched: false, TotalHealth: 3900000, RowOfEnemy: 1 }
]
```

If you want to change this order, please modify `<` and `>`.

#### Reference:

- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think it was that simple. worked just fine.